# Java recursive method for word matching

Tags: java, android, arrays, recursion

I have been banging my head against the wall trying to figure out why this recursive method isn't returning true when it matches a user supplied word.

I'm creating a 2D array with this logic:

```java
charTest = letterString.toCharArray();

    char[][] twoDimCharArray = new char[][] 
            {{charTest[0],charTest[1],charTest[2],charTest[3]},
            {charTest[4],charTest[5],charTest[6],charTest[7]},
            {charTest[8],charTest[9],charTest[10],charTest[11]},
            {charTest[12],charTest[13],charTest[14],charTest[15]}};
```

a user supplied string is passed into the following method with the expectation that if it checks against the 2D array and finds each character of the string in an adjoining position it will return true from the main method:

```java
public boolean findWord(String word) {
    for (int row = 0; row < this.board2.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < this.board2.length; col++) {
            if (this.findWord(word, row, col)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean findWord(String word, int row, int col) {
   if (    row < 0 || row >= this.board2.length ||
           col < 0 || col >= this.board2.length ||
           this.board2[row][col] != word.charAt(0)) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        char safe = this.board2[row][col];
        this.board2[row][col] = '*';
        String rest = word.substring(1, word.length());
       Log.v("rest", rest + "");
        boolean result = this.findWord(rest, row-1, col-1) ||
                this.findWord(rest, row-1,   col) ||
                this.findWord(rest, row-1, col+1) ||
                this.findWord(rest,   row, col-1) ||
                this.findWord(rest,   row, col+1) ||
                this.findWord(rest, row+1, col-1) ||
                this.findWord(rest, row+1,   col) ||
                this.findWord(rest, row+1, col+1);
        this.board2[row][col] = safe;
        return result;
    }
}
```

however the method always returns false regardless of the position of the characters. When I'm debugging it does appear to pass over every position in the array, but doesn't recognize a match for the first character and begin checking for the second. Does anything glaring stand out?

Comment: I'd guess `this.board2` is improperly shared between recursive calls and should be copied so each branch has it's own version, not the one already messed up by a neighboring branch.

Comment: What have you done to debug this?  At the very least, stick in print statements at the top and bottom of each routine to print the calling arguments and return status.  This will likely uncover the issue; if not, it will help show us where to look.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're missing a positive recursion termination case.  Revised `findWord()`:

```
private boolean findWord(String word, int row, int col) {

    if (row < 0 || row >= this.board2.length ||
        col < 0 || col >= this.board2.length ||
        this.board2[row][col] != word.charAt(0)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (word.length() == 1) {
        return true;
    }

    String rest = word.substring(1, word.length());

    char saved = this.board2[row][col];
    this.board2[row][col] = '*';

    boolean result = this.findWord(rest, row-1, col-1) ||
        this.findWord(rest, row-1,   col) ||
        this.findWord(rest, row-1, col+1) ||
        this.findWord(rest,   row, col-1) ||
        this.findWord(rest,   row, col+1) ||
        this.findWord(rest, row+1, col-1) ||
        this.findWord(rest, row+1,   col) ||
        this.findWord(rest, row+1, col+1);

    this.board2[row][col] = saved;

    return result;
}
```